# while uploading image I cannot see the content

Tags: node.js, mongodb, multer, gridfs

I have a problem uploading image file to my mongoDB using gridFS, but for some reason this doesn't work
this is my code :

```
const config = require("config");
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const dbURI = config.get("mongoURI");
const multer = require("multer");
const crypto = require("crypto");
const path = require("path");
const GridFsStorage = require("multer-gridfs-storage");

var storageImage = new GridFsStorage({
  url: dbURI,
  file: (req, file) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      crypto.randomBytes(16, (err, buf) => {
        if (err) {
          return reject(err);
        }
        const filename = buf.toString("hex") + path.extname(file.originalname);
        const fileInfo = {
          filename: filename,
          bucketName: "user_images"
        };
        resolve(fileInfo);
      });
    });
  }
});
const uploadImage = multer({ storageImage });



router.post("/uploadImage", uploadImage.single("userImg"), (req, res) => {
  console.log("uploading");
  console.log(req.file);
  res.json({ msg: "file uploaded successfully" });
});


module.exports = router;
```

when I console .log req.file I get undefined, does anyone know what the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem:

```
const uploadImage = multer({ storageImage });
```

it should be

```
const uploadImage= multer({storage:storageImage});
```